# Entity Framework and Stored PRocedures, how to remove Nullable paremeters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

Well I've been using Model-First with DbSet code generation. And now I what I want to do is to add some stored procedures.

But Code I get look like like:

```
        public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> CountPostsInThread(Nullable<int> threadID, ObjectParameter postCount)
    {
        var threadIDParameter = threadID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("threadID", threadID) :
            new ObjectParameter("threadID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("CountPostsInThread", threadIDParameter, postCount);
    }
```

Now, how Do I get rid off all those  ?
It's something wrong with tt files, or with my stored procedure ?
SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_CountPostsInThread
(
    @threadID int,
    @PostCount int = 0 OUTPUT
)   
AS
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM PostSet
    WHERE PostSet.ThreadID = @threadID
```

Comment: Your SP never sets `@PostCount`

Comment: I know, it's leftover from my experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the template or stored procedure. SP's parameters accept NULL value so because of that EF makes them nullable. The ternary operator is used because if you pass null EF must somehow pass the type of null parameter to correctly setup `SqlParameter` used internally.